# In Dart: I want to print a Setter (an int) with a string preceding it, for example: Car age: 7 years

Tags: dart

I have the following code:

```
class Vehicle {
    String make;
    String model;
    int manufactureYear;
    int vehicleAge;
    String color;
    
Vehicle({
    this.make,
    this.model,
    this.manufactureYear,
    this.color,
});
    
int get age {
    return vehicleAge;
}
    
void set age(int currentYear) {
    vehicleAge = currentYear - manufactureYear;
    }
}
    
void main() {
    Vehicle car = Vehicle(
    make: "Honda", model: "Civic", manufactureYear: 2005, color: "red");
    print("Car make: " + car.make); // output: Honda
    print("Car model: " + car.model); // output: Civic
    car.age = 2012;  // set age
    print(car.age); // output: calculated based on car.age value (7 in this case)
    print("Car color: " + car.color);
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Car make: Honda
Car model: Civic
7
Car color: red
```

Problem: I want to print "Car age: 7" instead of just "7"
What's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: `print('Car age: ${car.vehicleAge}')` . Read about it here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings